# why my code is not appending the first input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, append

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
def inchtofeet(inches):
    todosinches = []
    for i in inches:
        newinfeets = (i / 12.00)
        todosinches.append(newinfeets)
    return todosinches

def cubicfeet(feets):
    final = 1
    for i in feets:
        final = final * i

    return final * 11.00

def sumarcurrent(currents):
    suma = 0
    for i in currents:
        suma = suma + i
    return (str(suma) +'$')

start = True
listainput = []
inputcount = 0
solosuma = []
while start:
    inputinch = raw_input()
    print listainput
    if inputcount == 2:
        listadeinches = inchtofeet(listainput)
        print cubicfeet(listadeinches),'$'
        inputcount = 0
        listainput = []

    elif inputinch == 'stop':
        break
    elif inputinch == 'suma':
        print sumarcurrent(solosuma)
        solosuma = []
    else:
        listainput.append(int(inputinch))
        inputcount +=1
        continue
```

my code should get 3 inputs and then do a math, but the first input is not getting save in the list so after the fist input the list is still empty other 2 are getting save in the list

Comment: Could you mention your input and print of listainput after every iteration?

Comment: You never put any values in `solosuma` ...maybe in line `sumarcurrent(solosuma)` you mean `sumarcurrent(listainput)`?

Comment: @unMask my listainput is first [' '] second [' ', ' '] and third [' ', ' ' ], by using a print i figured out it wasent storing the last number dont know why

Comment: @Tiby Orfilas you didn't mention what is the value you are inputting here i.e. inputinch = raw_input() moreover, from your previous comment, does listainput contains only spaces? Quite interesting!!!

Comment: @unMask no my last reply was an example.. lets say first input is 1 second input is 2 and third input is 3 im passing it to inchtofeet() and just getting a list with 2 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works. As the latest input is not added to list - listainput, you are facing the issue.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
def inchtofeet(inches):
todosinches = []
for i in inches:
    newinfeets = (i / 12.00)
    todosinches.append(newinfeets)
print(todosinches)
return todosinches

def cubicfeet(feets):
    final = 1
    for i in feets:
        final = final * i
    return final * 11.00
def sumarcurrent(currents):
    suma = 0
    for i in currents:
        suma = suma + i
    return (str(suma) +'$')

start = True
listainput = []
inputcount = 0
solosuma = []
while start:
    inputinch = int(input("Hi give the inch:"))
    if inputcount == 2:
        listainput.append(inputinch)
        listadeinches = inchtofeet(listainput)
        print(cubicfeet(listadeinches),'$')
        inputcount = 0
        listainput = []

    elif inputinch == 9999:
        break
    elif inputinch == 9998:
        print(sumarcurrent(solosuma))
        solosuma = []
    else:
        listainput.append(inputinch)
        inputcount +=1
        print(listainput)
        continue
```

I did run and all the input entries were stored and used in the calculation.